# Attributes of a Variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, attributes

I took a quiz in my advanced C++ course and was surprised when I got points taken off from the following question:

*Specify four attributes of a variable in C++.*

My answer: *size, type, class, public*

Size and type were accepted but class and public weren't. My understanding is that an instance of a class is an attribute of the instantiated variable. And when defining a class, the member variables can be public or private attributes of the class.

I asked my TA and professor and they claim I am wrong because an instance variable is not the same as a data type variable like int, double, char, etc.

So my question boils down to: Do instances of a class act the same as primitive type variables? Why or why not?

Comment: Type and class are the same thing. (Or, rather, all classes are also types; not all types are classes.) But in normal English, type and class have equivalent meanings.

Comment: Not everything in C++ has to be of class type, so things like public access may or may not apply.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Noted, corrected.

Comment: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) for class vs type. class type is one out of many types. `public` only makes sense for member variables.

Comment: There is also storage and linkage: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: Since it is advanced c++ course, the question may refer to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).  However there are only two in standard for variables. `maybe_unused` and `deprecated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor was somewhat correct.

- Types are the property of "[o]bjects, references, functions including function template specializations, and expressions" ([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type))
- Classes refer to "user-defined types" ([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class))

Your instructor was probably looking for:

1. Size
2. Type
3. Name
4. Value

There are also other properties, such as Address and Linkage, but it is unlikely your professor was referring to those.

> My understanding is that an instance of a class is an attribute of the instantiated variable

No, it (the class) is the *type* of the variable (which is a property, as quoted above)

> And when defining a class, the member variables can be public or private attributes of the class.

Visibility only applies to a small subset of variables, and in the case of member variables, they can be marked `protected` in a class as well.

> Do instances of a class act the same as primitive type variables? Why or why not?

I don't understand what you mean by "act". If you mean, can they be assigned to, can they be passed to functions, do they use similar syntax, then yes. If you are referring to operations, their members, their size, then no.

Comment: class and type are not pretty much the same thing. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type

Comment: @user463035818 Better now?

Comment: sorry, but you made it worse by wrongly quoting cppref. You write "Types refer to "[o]bjects, references, functions including function template specializations, and expressions"" while the correct quote is "Objects, references, functions including function template specializations, and expressions have a property called type, ..." thats a different statement.

Comment: @user463035818 Doesn't matter, but am I correct now?

Comment: better, yes. Need some more letters, so I just make another stupid comment about the instructor...I actually was still considering a downvote before you added the "somewhat" ;)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.